# suコマンドでのshell指定

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

ログインシェルに`/bin/false`が指定されているユーザに `su username -s /bin/bash -lc "commend"` すると `su: using restricted shell /bin/false` というエラーで実行できません。
これは正常な動作でしょうか？
ご教授いただけたら幸いです。

環境
raspberry pi os version 10.7
bash version 5.0.3

以下を実行中でした

```
adduser --system --shell  /bin/false --home /opt/pleroma pleroma
export FLAVOUR="arm"
su pleroma -s $SHELL -lc "
curl 'https://git.pleroma.social/api/v4/projects/2/jobs/artifacts/stable/download?job=$FLAVOUR' -o /tmp/pleroma.zip
unzip /tmp/pleroma.zip -d /tmp/
"
```

[Installing on Linux using OTP releases - Pleroma Documentation](https://docs-develop.pleroma.social/backend/installation/otp_en/#installing-pleroma)

Comment: su pleroma -s /bin/bash -lc "id"は実行できますか？

Comment: できませんでした。`pi@room-pi:~ $ su pleroma -s /bin/bash -lc "id"
パスワード:
su: using restricted shell /bin/false`

Comment: rootユーザで実行してもだめですか？

Comment: straceを取ればエラーの原因が分かるかもしれません。「strace -f su pleroma -s /bin/bash -lc 'id'」

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。sudo su pleroma -s /bin/bash -lc "id"
uid=116(pleroma) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
これは、su でpleromaユーザにスイッチするにはpiユーザでは権限不足だったという事でしょうか？

Comment: pleromaはadduserの後にパスワード設定していないようです、パスワードを設定していないとrootユーザ以外ではエラーになると思います。パスワード設定をするのが正しいのかrootユーザで実行するのがよいのかはわかりませんが、adduserを実行しているのでrootユーザで実行するのが正しい気がします。rootユーザで本来やりたかったことはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 今回の現象とは直接関係しないと思いますが、$FLAVOURがシングルクォート内にあるのでarmに展開されないと思いますが大丈夫でしょうか？curl 'https://git.pleroma.social/api/v4/projects/2/jobs/artifacts/stable/download?job=$FLAVOUR' -o /tmp/pleroma.zip

Comment: 本来やりたかったcurlでのダウンロードとunzipができました。私の環境ではシンクグルクォート内変数も展開できました

Comment: 因みに、pleromaユーザのパスワードを設定しなくてもスイッチ時にパスワードを聞かれたのですが設定されたパスワードが分からず新たに設定していました。長々とお付き合い頂きありがとうございました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ログインシェルに/bin/falseが指定されているユーザでも`su username -s /bin/bash -lc "commend"`は実行可能です。
実行できない場合は他の原因が考えられます。